# C++ Basic "Questionnaire Game" Befuddling Error

Tags: c++, printing, conditional-statements

Basically, this program is supposed to question the user based on simple Yes and No answers on a mystery TA. At the end the user is asked to guess who the TA is by entering their name, and if the name is correct it's supposed to print so. However I am getting the same output no matter what I enter as the guess.

Is it a problem with my conditionals? Source as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/* define global variabless about TA */
string name = "Connor";

/* set all these as false until they get them right */
bool hairRight = false;
bool gfxArts = false;
bool ownsCat = false;
bool isJunior = false;
bool isGirl = false;
int score = 0;
string answer = ""; //used for user input
void questions()
{
    /* declare local variables */
    bool got_it = false; //right or wrong

    /* start loop */
    do {
        /* Pronmpt user */
        cout << "Does the TA have brown hair? Enter (Y) or (N)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if ( answer == "Y" || answer == "y" ){
                cout << "Yes, you are correct!" << endl;
                hairRight = true; //set answer to correct
                score += 1;
            }else if ( answer == "N" || answer == "n"){
                cout << "I'm sorry, you are incorrect." << endl;
                got_it  = false;
            }else{
                cout << "Oops! I think you mispressed a button!" << endl;
            }

        cout << "Does the TA enjoy graphic design? Enter (Y) or (N)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if ( answer == "Y" || answer == "y" ){
                cout << "Yes, you are correct!" << endl;
                gfxArts = true; //set answer to correct
                score += 1;
            }else if ( answer == "N" || answer == "n"){
                cout << "I'm sorry, you are incorrect." << endl;
                got_it = false;
            }else{
                cout << "Oops! I think you mispressed a button!" << endl;
            }

        cout << "Does this particular Ta enjoy programing?/ does this ta have have a cat? Enter (Y) or (N)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if ( answer == "Y" || answer == "y" ){
                cout << "As far as I know, that's a complete lie..." << endl;
                ownsCat = false; //set answer to correct
                score -= 1;
            }else if ( answer == "N" || answer == "n"){
                cout << "I'm sorry, you are incorrect." << endl;
                got_it  = false;
            }else{
                cout << "Oops! I think you mispressed a button!" << endl;
            }

        cout << "This specific TA is a junior. Enter (Y) or (N)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if ( answer == "Y" || answer == "y" ){
                cout << "Yes, you are correct!" << endl;
                isJunior = true;
                score += 1;
            }else if ( answer == "N" || answer == "n" ){
                cout << "I'm sorry, you are incorrect." << endl;
                got_it = false;
            }else{
                cout << "Oops! this TA has dark brown hair. good try though. " << endl;
            }

        cout << "Who is this mystery TA?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if(got_it == true){
            cout << "Yes, you got it right!" << endl;
            cout << "Score: " << score << "/5" << endl;
        }else {
        cout << "Nope, you're wrong." << endl;
        cout << "Score: " << score << "/5" << endl;
        cout << "Press Enter to Restart" << endl;
        }


        } while (got_it == false);
            /* tell user he/she is wrong */
}

int main()
{
    questions();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the problematic code:

```
    cout << "Who is this mystery TA?" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(got_it == true){
    cout << "Yes, you got it right!" << endl;
    cout << "Score: " << score << "/5" << endl;
}else {
cout << "Nope, you're wrong." << endl;
cout << "Score: " << score << "/5" << endl;
cout << "Press Enter to Restart" << endl;
}


} while (got_it == false);
    /* tell user he/she is wrong */
```

Using this also does not work:

```
if(name == "Connor" || name == "connor")
```

Comment: Where do you set got_it to true? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @jeffcarey You're right. Will fix now. But even with the second conditional I provided it still does not work. Returns correct regardless of input